# AWS EC2 security policies - Restricting users to certain instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I am trying to deploy several EC2 instances on AWS. One instance for each module of my system (an instance for billing module, an instance for transaction module and so on). So I want to give full access of an EC2 instance to a group working on that module while blocking rights to other EC2 instances on that account, for example developers working on billing should only be able to access the EC2 billing instance and nothing else. I cannot find a way to implement this through the IAM policies. Can someone please help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you talking abut SSH access to an instance, or are you talking about SSH plus all AWS management activities (like stop/start/tag), or are you trying to block HTTP access to the web server on an instance? What does "full access" mean in this scenario?

Comment: All AWS management activities(Start/stop/tag) plus SSH access.

Comment: There's no simple, perfect solution that does all of this. You can investigate Resource-Level Permissions and Condition Keys to control AWS management tasks for groups of instances (controlled by tag). You can't control SSH (or RDP) access using IAM. You can use native Linux (or Windows) features, for example by only uploading relevant SSH keys to the instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of arrangement is fully supported, where you can restrict users/groups to only instances which are tagged according to your security and access model.

Here is good blog with examples about Restricting users to tagged instances.

From Demystifying [EC2 Resource-Level Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/demystifying-ec2-resource-level-permissions/)

> Now let’s take this one step further. One benefit of resource-level
>   permissions is that you can use them to take advantage of EC2 tags.
>   For example, you can make sure that a user can stop, terminate, or
>   restart instances in us-east-1 **only if the instance has a tag named
>   Environment that’s set to Prod**. With this change, the policy now looks
>   like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:Describe*"],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ThisActionSupportsResourceLevelPermissionsWithInstancesButNotWithTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances"],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissionsWithInstancesAndTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/Environment": "Prod"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As others suggested, this does not limit SSH access. For this, your would only provision keys to instances for the users/groups that have access. You could maintain a list of uses for each group, and at provision time, provision only the users to the group assigned via tag.

Answer (score 3):

**Without AWS Level Permission**

First of all if it is about SSH access (Or Remote Desktop if Windows) to the EC2 instances, then you can do it without the need of IAM or other AWS specific access control mechanism.

- Share the SSH Keys only with the admins who needs to access each server.
- Create Keys for each user and add them to the EC2 instances so that the users with Keys can access the server.

Note: Also remember to whitelist their IP's using Security groups not allowing any unauthorized access from different networks.

**With AWS IAM Permissions**

If you want to allow VPC, Autoscaling, Load Balancing and other configuration, then you can create IAM users with fine-grained access for those (Not for the EC2). But practically it will be challenging to do so since it will require quite a lot of effort to write the fine-grained policies as well as to maintain and modify them when new users comes in.

One of the strategies some companies use is to create multiple AWS accounts and deploy the servers in each where a sub group can be granted access to the account. You can create Consolidated billing and use AWS Organizations for Billing and Governance. However this is possible, if the dependency between each EC2 instance is not at VPC level.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group in `IAM` and include developers by using Users into the group.

Do the same and create another group for another instance.

Upon launching 2 individual `EC2` instances, generate unique `KeyPair` for both instance and share them to only the developers that you intended for them to have access on.

Comment: How are you proposing to tie an IAM group to a specific EC2 instance?

Comment: @jarmod: Sorry for understood the question wrongly, I've updated my answer, please help verify if it's workable for the situation?

Comment: Yes, selective distribution of keypairs would work for restricting SSH access, but you also mentioned adding users to IAM groups and that's not a viable solution here.

Comment: `for example developers working on billing should only be able to access the EC2 billing instance and nothing else` The group is to attach policy and to handle the "nothing else" or "some specific resources" although we can achieve the same by applying role to EC2. Just an option for the OP

Comment: Your answer, as stated, is insufficient. You would need to elaborate significantly by providing specifics of IAM policies and DevOps practices that would achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS OpsWork to manage EC2 instances access to user its very  simple...
For more info you can go through the link:
[AWS OpsWork](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/security-ssh-access.html)